# Invite via facebook from android app?? Not working well

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The following works perfectly:

1. Sending invite via facebook from my android app.
2. Receiving the notification about the request on facebook website /facebook android
   app.

Problem:

When the user clicks the notification in his facebook android app, it directly opens a link in browser rather than opening a playstore for downloading the app from playstore.

Worked perfectly in versions 4.2.1 and lower, (redirected to playstore)

Why or what could be the reason?

Comment: what's the url that it's opening?

Comment: yes , it's a link similar like the following : app.facebook. but in some devices it worked perfect :redirecting to playstore......

Comment: It seems like a bug in latest facebook SDK. I have posted a question to helpdesk here https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=805495726128165, but still no answer